# To display Headerview with image and labels in the viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, http-headers, grouped-table

I am new to iPhone development. I have created one view controller and I used grouped table view. Now I want to display the header view in my viewcontroller with image and labels. Please guide me and help me out in this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with header view?

Comment: i have used "viewForHeaderInSection"  method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean a headerView or a sectionHeaderView? You can add subviews to the headerView in the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 225)];
    label.text = @"BlaBla";
    [self.tableHeaderView addSubview:label];
}
```

You specify size and position of the label with the `initWithFrame` method, and add the label as subview to the tableHeaderView - you can do this with multiple labels.

If you mean the sectionHeader you have to implement the `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` method, where you have to create a new view, and add different subviews to it:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 40)];
    label.text = @"BlaBla";
    [view addSubview:label];
    [label release];

    return [view autorelease];
}
```

In this case you also have to implement the method `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` which has to return the height of the view you create in the above method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 50.0f;
}
```